# NiFi Coordinator - Handle Data

Tags: apache-nifi

In NiFi 1.0.0, I understand that there is a Zero-Master paradigm wherein one node is elected the cluster coordinator. Does the coordinator also process data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes in Apache NiFi 1.x the cluster coordinator works just like any other node in the cluster in terms of processing data, it just has additional responsibilities for receiving heartbeats from the other cluster nodes, and managing joining/disconnecting of other nodes.

This is different from the 0.x baseline where the NCM did not process any data.